# How to upload a large file to OneDrive using Microsoft Graph

Tags: microsoft-graph-api, onedrive

I'm getting a `404 - File name not provided in url` response when [creating an upload session](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/onedrive/developer/rest-api/api/driveitem_createuploadsession).

My request looks like (without any body):

```http
POST /v1.0/drives/{drive-id}/items/{item-id}/createUploadSession
Authorization: bearer <token>
Content-Type: application/json
```

This problem is only with the consumer OneDrive, OneDrive for Business works fine.

Comment: What are you passing in for `{item-id}`?

Comment: @Marc I'm passing the file ID, the file has already been uploaded so it has got its own file ID, with above request I want to modify that file. The problem is only with personal account, for business account this works fine.

Comment: Have you tried using the `/root:/{item-path}:/` method in place of `/items/{item-id}`? It shouldn't matter but it may also be worth trying `/me` since consumer OneDrive only has a single `drive` (i.e. `/me/drive/items/{itemId}`).

Comment: I have used `/root:/{item-path}:`  method for my own drive's files. Some user  has shared a folder with me which I have added to my One-drive. Regardless the type of account I wanted to make changes in this shared directory which requires drive ID to access, so can't use the path.

Comment: You can still use a path: `/drives/{id}/root:/{path}:/` but this is unlikely your problem. It sounds like you're attempting to upload a file into the folder someone shared with you. This may not be possible.

Comment: According to following documentation [link](https://developer.microsoft.com/en-us/graph/docs/api-reference/v1.0/api/driveitem_createuploadsession), I have used the request `POST /drives/{driveId}/items/{itemId}/createUploadSession`  , which works for shared folder of business account only( I have editable permission for shared folder). It is not mentioned anywhere in the documentation, why it is not working for personal account. So with no options left I'm using  `/drives/{id}/root:/{path}:/` for this particular case

Answer (score -1, accepted):

I've never run across your particular scenario but I suspect this is due to the folder that was shared with you via OneDrive for Business being part of the same tenant as your own OneDrive for Business. When you're accessing a shared folder from a consumer OneDrive however, you are effectively accessing a drive in a completely separate tenant.

Since using the `root:/{path}:/` method I suggested works, it sounds like this scenario may cause some issues with the API determining the file's information from the `{itemId}`. I'm looking to confirm this so I can update the documentation going forward.

Comment: Okay, but the request `POST /v1.0/drives/{drive-id}/items/{item-id}/createUploadSession` doesn't work for personal account for my own file as well as for shared ones for sure. The error I get is "File name not provided in url".

Answer (score 0):

It worked for me:-

```
POST - https://graph.microsoft.com/v1.0/me/drive/root:/filename.txt:/createUploadSession

In Headers:-
Content-Type : application/json
Authorization: Bearer EwCIA8l6BAAUO...9chh8cJaAg==

In Body:- 
{
  "item": {
    "@odata.type": "microsoft.graph.driveItemUploadableProperties",
    "@microsoft.graph.conflictBehavior": "rename",
    "name": "filename.txt"
  }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

I could upload a file in a personal account using this URL for create the storage session:

[https://graph.microsoft.com/v1.0/me/drive/items/{folderID}:/{fileID}:/createUploadSession](https://graph.microsoft.com/v1.0/me/drive/items/%7BfolderID%7D:/%7BfileID%7D:/createUploadSession)

```
var config = {
  method: 'post', 
url: 'https://graph.microsoft.com/v1.0/me/drive/items/{folderID}:/{fileID}:/createUploadSession',
  headers: { 
    'Content-Type': 'application/json', 
    'Authorization': 'Bearer
}
```

Response:

```
{
    "@odata.context": "https://graph.microsoft.com/v1.0/$metadata#microsoft.graph.uploadSession",
    "expirationDateTime": "2020-11-06T14:25:27.662Z",
    "nextExpectedRanges": [
        "0-"
    ],
    "uploadUrl": {url}
}
```

Then:

To create the file you gonna need to send a PUT request for the
{uploadUrl} that you got in the response.